# Are there any R functions which support Reversible Jump MCMC for a GLM or SGLM?

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I would like to perform reversible jump on a network model, but before arriving there, I'm wondering if there are any R packages which support reversible jump for a user specified generalized linear model or spatial-GLM?

Something as simple as an RJMCMC procedure (in R) for the selection of predictors in a logistic regression would be a nice place for me to start?  Does such a function exist?

Through googling, I've only found [RJaCGH](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJaCGH/index.html) which appears to be a bit more complicated (and application specific) than I was hoping for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinBUGS has support for RJMCMC with an addon. I've used it for GLMs, including those with an intrinsic CAR component. Not R, obviously, but through R2WinBUGS you can patch them together.